# Display PNG base64 encoded in html after ajax request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, image

I currently facing a problem that I can not solve.

I have a django app that trigger speed-test and send back data and base64 encoded image in json object. A ajax request ask for the test and the response is the JSON. However I can not display the image in the HTML.

My jquery :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#chargement').show();
    $(document).load(dynamicTask());

    function dynamicTask() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url "rfa.views.dynamicSpeedtest" %}",
            data: {ip: "{{ ip }}", timelength: "{{ timelength }}", interval: "{{ interval }}", bandwidth: "{{ bandwidth }}", jitter: "{{ jitter }}", pktLoss:"{{ pktLoss }}", delay: "{{ delay }}", retransmit: "{{ retransmit }}"},

                success: function(data) {
                    $('#chargement').hide();
                    console.log("success");
                    $.each(data.tab, function(i, obj){
                            $("#resultat> tbody:last").append("<tr> <td> " + obj.Indicateur + " </td> <td> " + obj.Minimum + " </td> <td> " + obj.Moyenne + "</td> <td> " + obj.Maximum + " </td> </tr>");
                    }
                    );
                    $.each(data.images, function(j, img){

                    $('#imageslist').html('<img src="' + img.src + '"/>');


                    }
                    );
                },
                error: function(){
                    $('#chargement').hide();
                    }, 

        })
    }
})
```

The json I received :

```
{
    "tab": [
        {
            "Indicateur": "Bande passante",
            "Maximum": "27.6GB/s",
            "Minimum": "26.9GB/s",
            "Moyenne": "27398800000.0"
        },
        {
            "Indicateur": "Delai",
            "Maximum": "0.0925ms",
            "Minimum":    "0.024ms",
            "Moyenne": "0.0458ms"
        },
        {
            "Indicateur": "Gigue",
            "Maximum": "0.051784 bits/s",
            "Minimum": "0.0100943 bits/s",
            "Moyenne": "0.03211228ms"
        }
    ],
    "images": [
        {
            "src": "data: image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,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"
        },
        {
            "src": "data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64, 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"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try posting the question with a demostration of your problem in jsfiddle / Plunker

Comment: I try but it does not work even for the part that already work (getting the data from the tzab part of my json). [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cxeqwyu8/#&togetherjs=nQim4N9B7I)
My problem is diplaying the picture i send in a json in base 64

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Your code overwrites the images so you only see the last image in the images array.
2. The last image in your sample JSON is probably corrupted. when I switched the order of the images the other one rendered just fine (a horizontal ruler image)

You can see the core workings in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/v6cR9k9FK6iq1rNbCbVu?p=preview

```
"images": [

        {
            "src": "data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,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"
        },
        {
            "src": "data: image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,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"
        }
    ]
```

**edit:**
In order to append all images use `append` instead of `html`.
updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/v6cR9k9FK6iq1rNbCbVu?p=preview

Comment: hi ! thanks for reply. how can i change my code in order to not overwrite my image? (ie create one image for each base64 image of the JSON?

Comment: you can probably use jQuery's `append` instead of `html`

Comment: I already try it :s It resulting in creating img with invalid url (whereas base64 encoded images are correct)

Answer (score 0):

i finally solve the problem by creating static  html  with src attribute empty. then, my jquery fill this src attribute getting each  by id (image0, image1, image2 and image3). It is not the best choice  i know but i m not really a good web dev. 
Thanks for answering me ! :)